# No matter what i do its giving this error TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. Please help

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\usepackage{todo}
\usepackage{hyper}
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
\title{Packages in LATEX}
\author{anandajiththarol }
\date{November 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{answers}
Answers  is package used to create question and answer sheet using latex very easily.This  package  is  a  modification  of  the   previous  style  option answers,which  has  been  in  use  for  a  few  years,  and  was  based  upon  the  TEXbook  idea of binding solutions to exercises.
\newline
\textbf{\textit{Example:}}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]
 \subsection{Problems}
 \begin{ex}
 First exercise
 \begin{sol}
 First solution.
 \end{sol}
 \end{ex}
 \begin{ex}
 Second exercise
 \begin{sol}
 Second solution.
 \end{sol}
 \end{ex}
 \Closesolutionfile{ans}
 \subsection{Solutions}
 \input{ans1}

\section{newcommand}
Newcommand is a latex package to define new macros. Only one argument can be designated as optional, it must be the first argument, and it must appear within square brackets.  Defining macros that take multiple optional arguments or in which an optional argument appears in the middle of the argument list is possible but is somewhat complicated.
\newline
\textbf{\textit{Example}}
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}} 
\begin{align*}
     x &=ut+\frac{1}{2}*(at^2)\\
     x &=\frac{1}{2}*gt^2\\
      g &=\frac{2x}{t^2} \numberthis\label{eq1}
\end{align*}
In the above quation a custom macro, numberthis is used to label an equation.
\section{Attachfile}
his package defines an attachfilecommand that lets you attach arbitrary files to a pdf document. These files are embedded right in the pdf file, so they get transmitted along with it. The package also gives you control over the corresponding icon’s properties and various other associated metadata.
\newline
\textbf{\textit{Example}}
\attachfile{attach.txt}\\
Here a sample txt is attached to the document using the attchfile package.\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using the `hyper` package? It is causing the trouble it seems. It has not been updated in 20 years. If you need hyperlinks use the `hyperref` package instead

Comment: Yeah that fixed it thank you

Answer (score 2):

I've never even seen the `hyper` package before. It seems to be the problem. Looking at it, the `hyper` package has not been updated in 20 years. It is probably a better idea to use the more modern `hyperref` package instead. Remember that `hyperref` has to be loaded as the last package (with small number of exceptions).